# initialViewController in storyboard crashes with Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Really weird problem, I made an app with a storyboard that run fine on device and simulator. Ad hoc distribution run fine too. There are no errant IBOutlets, and the storyboard is bundled in the xarchive. When its submitted to the app store though, they are coming back with a crash log of:

```
2014-11-24 07:18:26.349 TestApp[327]: <Error> assertion failed: 12B411: libxpc.dylib + 71820 [AD580443-238D-3997-8D09-004C210D0C18]: 0x7d
2014-11-24 07:18:26.455 TestApp[327]: <Error> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6536A480-C478-49C8-8C77-C1C327C96658/TestApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-Ltq-wg-xoP' and directory 'TestApp.storyboardc''
```

That's just in `[UIApplication _run]` so its not being loaded programmatically but rather its just the `initialViewController` set in the storyboard.

Really at a loss as to how to reproduce this crash.